# How do I disable the "SECURITY FREEZE LOCK" on my SATA hard disk?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ioctl, ssd, sata

I am sending ATA commands to SATA HDD using IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH in windows. IDENTIFY DEVICE (ECh) ATA commands returns 256 words of data.
Word 128, Bit 3 is set in the returned data, and according to ATA specs the bit denotes Device is in security frozen mode.
Because of that, ATA Security Commands are getting aborted. I tried power off/Hardware Reset as mentioned in ATA specs to disable Security Frozen mode.
But the device is stil in security frozen state. I am doubting on windows atapi / ataport driver for making HDD security frozen.

How to disable this security frozen mode?? Please Help me...

Comment: Isn't the whole point of security freeze that the disk's contents can't be accessed anymore?

Comment: Disk contents can be accessed, but only ATA security commands(like security set passwword, disable password etc..) will get aborted. Remaining commands are running well.

Comment: [Relevant](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase#Step_1a_-_Ensure_the_drive_is_not_frozen:).